# Getting the circle boundary

Tags: matlab

I have a logical circular mask of 0 and 1 in my matrix which looks the following way.

[image: Mask]

What is the fastest way to get just the outside boundary in another matrix ?

Essentially I have to scan for the first 1 from left and first 1 from right in each row if there are duplicate 1's in the row ( there will be just one 1 in the topmost , bottommost points ).... Can someone help me in finding a fast way to do this ?

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/09/04/detecting-circular-objects-in-images/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are good for finding general circles in images, but since you know that you're looking for a circle in a binary mask, bwmorph is probably your best bet.

```
I=imread('0ateM.png');
BW=im2bw(I);
BW2=bwmorph(BW,'endpoints');
```

[image: image after bwmorph]
Edit:
As I mentioned in the comments, in order to enlarge the circle so that you're getting the 0 pixels just outside the original circle mask set to 1 and everything else set to 0, you can invert the original mask and then use bwmorph:

```
WB=-(BW-1);
WB2=bwmorph(WB,'endpoints');
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect that the border of the image is changed to 1's. Of course you can easily change this. For an mxn image:

```
WB2(1,:)=0; WB2(:,1)=0; WB2(:,n)=0; WB2(m,:)=0;
```

An alternative approach is to directly use a filter on the original image:

```
f=[1 1 1; 1 -9 1; 1 1 1];
G=filter2(f,BW);
BW2=im2bw(G);
```

This will achieve the same results as WB2 above without the white border problem. The `im2bw` call is needed because after the filter the values are no longer just 0 or 1, they range somewhere between -8 and 8 and we want the negative values to be 0 and the positive values to be 1.

Comment: Hey , one question regarding the above picture... is there an easy way to expand the above circle by 1 pixel ?

Comment: Just as a guess, invert the image, and use bwmorph on the result.

Comment: Yeah, inverting works, but it has the added effect that it puts a white border around the image 1 pixel wide.

Comment: What do i need to give as parameter for the inside circle in bwmorph ?

Comment: I used `WB = -(BW - 1);` to invert, then `WB2 = bwmorph(WB,'endpoints');`. You should be able to accomplish the same thing with `filter2()` but I'd have to play with it a bit. Something like [1 1 1; 1 -9 1; 1 1 1]. I'll try it in a little while.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) for that, here are a few examples that identify circles:

- [link1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42587-detect-certain-shapes-in-binary)
- [link2](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexroundness.html)
- [link3](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/06/21/advanced-maneuvers-with-regionprops/)

or if you're sure there's only one circle and no noise, I assume you can just find the bottom/top/left/right edge and work from that:

```
m = loadcirclefunction();
pix_left  = find(any(m,1),1,'first');
pix_right = find(any(m,1),1,'last');
pix_top   = find(any(m,2),1,'first');
pix_bottom= find(any(m,2),1,'last');
```

Comment: Hey , when I am using the plot function to plot the above points I get them correctly but when I plot the circle using the viscircles determining the center and radii I get some irregularities. Since I need to get the values from the outside of the circle in a concentric manner can I assume that viscircles is slightly off ?

Comment: which 'above points'? what irregularities? I have no clue what you're talking about.. Better ask in a new question or edit your question [specifically detailing what your problem is, what you've tried, what the results are,...](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

**Brute force is linear with the size of image,** and since you need to copy the image it's my opinion that *you can't gain much by improving your method*. Nonetheless, it should be pretty fast, and it works for any number of circles on the image.

```
function bound = find_bound(circle)

[sy sx] = size(circle);
bound = circle;

for i = 2:sy-1
    for j = 2:sx-1
        if (~circle(i,j))
            bound(i,j) = any((circle(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)-circle(i,j))(:));
        end
    end
end
```